# JUnit using assertEquals with double

Tags: junit

Am a beginner to both Java and JUnit.  I need to write a small program converting Fahrenheit to Celsius and test with JUnit in Eclipse.

Both the celsius and fahrenheit need to be set to double.  I am aware when testing using the assertEquals, the method needs to be Assert.assertEquals(double expected, double acutal, double delta).

So am assuming the double expected should be 'celsius', double actual should be 'fahrenheit', what should the double delta be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expected and actual should be checked w.r.t to Celsius.

Eg :

```
assertEquals(37.77,App.converFarenheitToCelsius(100), 0.01);
```

0.01 is

> the maximum delta between expecteds[i] and actuals[i] for which both numbers are still considered equal.